# Google Spreadsheet function for multiple variables giving one result

Tags: google-sheets, match, google-sheets-formula, gs-vlookup

So, it might be a silly question, but I find it really difficult to search for an answer with a simple query and felt like I needed to post a more complex question to get my point across and get an answer. Really sorry if this has been asked before, but I'm not a native Eng speaker and I don't know which phrases to sue when looking for this.

What I want to do is create a Google Spreadsheet to ease character creation for an RPG game for my friends.

There are lots of choices during creation, of course, and I need to be able to get one result from multiple variables. To make it clear, I'll use an example from creation:

It's based on priority system A-E. If the player chooses priority A for race and chooses human as race, they get 9 points to spend on attributes.

I need a function that would check one cell for priority letter, the other for race name and give me a result based on those two, so in the given example, it'd be something like:
'if A2 = "A" and B2 = "Human" then C2 = 9.

I know it's entirely not how functions are written, but I'm trying to describe the calculation I'm trying to run.

I'd be grateful for any and all the help!

Comment: @player0 [Here! :)](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1BGGiYIqxAAHZadWb973Xi6j5ejl75fbcllnqRZPhz9g/edit?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try something like:

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A10; A1:F8; MATCH(B10; A1:F1; 0); 0))
```

[image: 0]